# Wrong json interpretation in IE and FF, working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem that remains a mystery to me.... I have a page that performs an AJAX call and receives a JSON result.
The results are ok in Chrome, but for some reason for certain value I get "null" in IE and FF.
The weirdest thing is that the JSON output looks exactly the same for two variables, yet one is working and the other one isnt.

The JSON output looks like this for example

```
[{"color":"#000000","size":8,"lat":36.7167,"lon":3.25,"name":"Algiers","region":"","temp":18.3,"mintemp":15,"maxtemp":21.7,"content":"","humidity":77,"rain":691,"sunlight":467,{"color":"#000000","size":8,"lat":-8.85,"lon":13.2333,"name":"Luanda","region":"","temp":25.1,"mintemp":21.9,"maxtemp":28.3,"content":"","humidity":79,"rain":367,"sunlight":384}
```

I receive the result and when I try for example alert(json[0].size) and alert(json[0].lat) I get null for the first one and 36.7167 for the second one...

In Chrome I get the correct value of 8 for size, but for FF and IE I keep on getting null, even though the output as you can see is exactly the same and even my PHP generates it in the exact same way, using the 
print json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); When I tried converting it to string I get a blank value and when converting to decimal, I get "0". I then tried to gettypeof and I get that both values are strings. So they are of same data type.

Here is the relevant part of the code for generating the JSON response (the size function is ok, it works and returns correct values and both end variables are of string type):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con_climate,"
 SELECT *
 FROM complete 
 $string"
 );

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $lat = $row['Lat'];
}
$size_original = $_GET['size'];

function size($value,$scale_min,$scale_max,$value_min,$value_max){
  $scale_min = $scale_min - 0.001;
  $scale_max = $scale_max + 0.001;
  $scale_perc = ($scale_max-$scale_min)/100;
  $percentage = ($value-$scale_min)/$scale_perc;
  $size_perc = ($value_max-$value_min)/100;
  $calculated = $size_perc*$percentage+$value_min;
  return $calculated;
}
$size = size( $size_original,-15,15,-10,10);

$results = array();
$results['size'] = $size;
$results['lat'] = $lat;

array_push($data, $results);

print json_encode($data);
```

And the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "text/JSON",
    dataType: "json",
    url: file,
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json[0].lat;
        alert(json[0].size;
    },
});
```

I just randomly chose some values above, but basically I get then two alerts, one is the correct number (for lat), the other one being "null", but in Chrome and Opera, the correct number as well. And the JSON output looks like I showed above in all browsers...

[Here](http://meteopage.com/climate/climate_map_ajax.php?&continents=%27Africa%27&countries=&capital=1&color=auto&autocolor=000000&size=auto&autosize=8&label=none) is the JSON.

Comment: sorry here is the correct JSON output:
http://meteopage.com/climate/climate_map_ajax.php?&continents=%27Africa%27&countries=&capital=1&color=auto&autocolor=000000&size=auto&autosize=8&label=none

Comment: It works fine for me in IE7 and IE12. Can you reproduce it in a jsFiddle or something similar?

Comment: Actually, maybe `contentType: "text/JSON"` is the offender. Try `"application/json"`.

Comment: As Halcyon mentioned, try changing the content type to the correct `application/json`. I also recommend fixing the content type in your HTTP response as well by using the something like `header('Content-Type: application/json')` in your PHP code.

Comment: OK, I am not sure how to completely reproduce it in JSFiddle, but try this:

Go here: http://meteopage.com/climate/climate_map.php and for "kontinent" select for example Africa, and then check the checkbox on the right which means "only capitals" and then click on "Zobrazit" (Show). 

In Chrome I get alert with two numbers (and then the numbers are used in the script), in FF and IE I get first alert "null" second the correct number. 

The JSON output for that looks like the above

Comment: the first "lat" is interpreted correctly, the markers on the map are generated in the correct position, their size however is "null"

Comment: @Halcyon GET requests have no content body so contentType will probably be ignored

Comment: Look at: http://meteopage.com/climate/climate_map_ajax.php?&continents=%27Africa%27&countries=&label=none the values are `null`.

Comment: yes, I added the header and changed the application/json as well and still the same problem

Comment: yes, chrome gives me both values correctly, opera too, json response looks exactly the same in all browsers, IE and FF give null and the number, Chrome and Opera alert two numbers (which is the correct behavior)

Comment: Well, your response looks incorrect so I have no idea how Chrome is able to give the correct answer.

Comment: before I tried converting it to double and float and then in the JSON response there were no " " " in front and behind the number, the result was the same. Chrome and opera correct, FF and IE null for the first one, number for second.

Comment: the response currently looks like this http://meteopage.com/climate/climate_map_ajax.php?&continents=%27Africa%27&countries=&capital=1&color=auto&autocolor=000000&size=auto&autosize=8&label=none and when I put alert for lat and size I get null and number... even though in the response they look exactly the same

Comment: and when I tried multiplying it by 1, just to make sure it is a number, then I get the two correct numbers in Opera and Chrome and IE and FF alert lat correctly and the other one instead "null" alerts as "0" (even though the response is 8)

Comment: I found the problem.... it has to do with the generation of the actual URL for the AJAX call, for some reason FF and IE are not able to interpret correctly the value of a select box